# How is it possible for me to hear the audio of multiple different videos on my computer?

Tags: operating-systems, io, multi-processor, multi-threaded

I am reading [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013230998X) and so far, being in chapter 3, I understand that multiprogramming and multiprocessing allows for faster execution of multiple existing processes/threads. I am reading into all of their intricacies and so far understanding everything just fine. However it is also mentioned that while a program uses I/O modules, another program has a to wait, implying numerous times that two programs cannot use I/O modules at the same time.

Perhaps I am asking too soon and this is covered somewhere later in the book, but right now -at this moment- I cannot help wondering how can I possibly have, say, VLC media player and Windows Media Player playing, each, different videos on my computer and yet have the audio be a combination of the sound of both videos. Is it perhaps that the execution of processes in the I/O have some sort of a timer too? Or is it maybe that my computer has multiple I/O (in this case audio/speaker) modules? If so, is there a limit? Is there somewhere in this book that I can jump on for a little while to read on it? Or perhaps some website that explains it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to consider.
first note that analog audio is different than digital audio which is usually streamed at a bitrate of 48khz (analog bitrate is theoretically infinite). if you looked at it with greater frequency (like maybe 1Mhz), you would see "holes" between the bits, and you can use the time to do other things, like processing a second stream.

Second note that the [southbridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_%28computing%29) handles audio codec processing, so the stream doesn't need to pass the entire length of the system bus. between the southbridge and the sound card itself, a lot of the processing is done close to the source bus (the [superIO controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_I/O))

Third note that the southbridge has multiple connections to the SuperIO controller, and the bus between them (in modern computing) is measured in GHz, as is the Sata bitrate.

Fourth, note that streams are a continuous phenomena, so a thread reading a stream from disk doesn't "complete" in time that it could then yield execution to another thread in a synchronous manner. in this case input is buffered while other threads are executing, if the system can't provide an execution unit to the thread continuously. the system has to be able to time-slice them, or a single core system could never play a sound file. That said though, the CPU doesn't do much with audio processing.

HD audio at high bitrates can stress system buses, and present issues with multithreading while maintaining smooth playback. Windows Vista+ throttle other southbridge stream services like the [network card](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1045925/vista-audio-throttles-network-speed) to ensure smooth playback, but a well provisioned system without signifigant load would have little trouble rendering a couple streams seemingly simultaneously.

so, all told, even if your system was limited on IO modules, the audio is slow enough to time-slice, relies on hardware and buses grouped together to avoid bottle necks with other system components, and doesn't stress the actual IO channel.

Comment: Within my little knowledge that made a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple software modules that feed into the software mixer module that feeds the hardware. Each application keeps a queue of sound data non-empty as the mixer module combines the inputs to produce a single output that drives the hardware.

Comment: Anywhere where I can read more on this?